# $scope.url relative and absolute path

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

$scope.currentProduct.files[0].file contains sometimes a relative URL (/images/aaa.png) and sometimes an absolute URL (http://www.sth.com/images/aaa.png)

Is there a way to resolve this using ng-src ?

Thanks in advance,
Jérémie.

Comment: not really without some ugly code in the view. Normalize them when you receive them

Comment: use a controller to fix it, it would check the one that does not have an absolute URL and convert them